Unable to Display Images in Google Colab
This google colab cell doesn't show any image, how to fix it?
First I connect to google drive and set working directory.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks")

Then in Markdown cell I have this:
# Optional Lab: Model Representation
<figure>
 <img src="C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png"   style="width:600px;height:200px;">
</figure>


Neither of this worked as well, even when I use absolute path.
![Image Title](C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png)

![Image Title](/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png)

<img src="C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png" alt="Image Title">


Checking for files in current directory:
!ls 
 C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png             'Test read drive contents.ipynb'
 temp.txt

It can read other files in the folder though:
readfile = open("temp.txt", 'r').read()
readfile
'test'

Additionally, this method worked but its not what I am looking for since all lecture notebooks are formated using <figure> </figure> I won't be able to reformat everything.
from IPython.display import Image, display
display(Image(filename='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/C1_W1_L3_S1_Lecture_b.png'))


did you try to use /full/path/to/image in <img src="...">?

problem is security system. Google doesn't allow to direct access to files. You have to generate special link using function share on Google Drive. And it still may need to convert link to embed like in How to Embed Images from Google Drive on your Website - Digital Inspiration

BTW: code display(Image(...)) works because code loads your file and it converts it to string encoded base64 and it adds this string instead of url in src in <img src="data:image/png;base64,...encoded image..."
